# Tweepy: Always display emoji in "\ud83d\ude4c" format from tweet text

Tags: python, twitter, unicode, tweepy, emoji

### My question

When streaming data using tweepy, I receive the intended result of

```
Tweet Contents: RT @ChickSoPretty: Zendaya tho \ud83d\ude4c https:....
```

When using the code

```
def on_data(self, data):
    username = data.split(',"screen_name":"')[1].split('","location"')[0]
    tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
    print("Tweet Contents: " + tweet)
```

--- *I am currently tracking **u'\U0001f64c'**, the code for an emoji.* ---

However, when I try to output the rest of the user's recent tweets...

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=username).items(20):
    tweet = status.text
    print("Tweet Contents: " + tweet)
```

Where 'username' is the user who has recently used an emoji, my program crashes.

This is understandable, as I am now trying to print an emoji onto the console,  instead of what I initially did, which was instead display the Javascript Escape code, **\ud83d\ude4c**.

My question is, how can I read through the statuses of a user and output their tweets in the first format?

### The purpose of my code

My long term goal is to iterate through the statuses of a user, and check how many emojis they used in their latest 20 tweets (including RT and replies).

I have "successfully created" some messy code for detecting emojis in tweets when emojis are displayed in the Javascript/Java Escape format, as follows...

```
for character in tweet:
  iteration = iteration + 1
  if(iteration < tweetLength):
    if tweet[iteration] == '\\' and tweet[iteration + 1] == 'u' and tweet[iteration + 6] == '\\' and tweet[iteration + 7] == 'u':           
    for x in range(0,12):
      emojiCode += tweet[iteration + x]                                        
      numberOfEmojis = numberOfEmojis + 1
      print("Emoji Code Found: "+emojiCode)  
      emojiCode = ""          
      iteration = iteration + 7
```

Wow, what a mess. But, it works for what I need it to do (only english tweets).

Is there a better way? Should I scrap this and use

```
tweet.encode('utf-8')
```

and try to find emojis in the following output format?

```
b'@Jathey3 @zachnahra31 this hard\xf0\x9f\x98\x82 we gotta do this https:...'
```

I am using Python 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

Yes: don't try to handle JSON-formatted data using low-level character-by-character string fiddling. There are tools available in the standard library that can do this quicker and more reliably.

Searching for the JSON-string-literal-encoded form of a character is tricky, because you don't know whether it's going to be included as `\ud83d\ude4c` or simply the raw character  (U+1F64C Person Raising Both Hands In Celebration). And any other non-emoji character might be encoded as an `\u` escape too, for example `\u0061\u0061` is `aa`. There are also rules about what happens when you have double-backslash or escaped quotes, which are hard to deal with at the same time as looking for a character, and there are any number of problems with property order and whitespace formatting when you're trying to find the property you want.

Avoid all these traps by using the `json` module's `loads` method to decode the JSON string into a Python dictionary containing raw strings you can inspect directly.

Then to find characters within a certain range, there are regular expressions, provided by the `re` module.

Finally, if you want to display output in JSON-format as `\ud83d\ude4c`, you can using the `json.dumps` method to encode that output back to JSON.

```
# Assuming input like:
json_input= '{"screen_name":"fred","location":"home","text":"Here is an emoji: ... and here is another one "}'

import json, re
emoji_pattern = re.compile('[\U0001F300-\U0001F64F]')

dict_input = json.loads(json_input)
text = dict_input['text']
screen_name = dict_input['screen_name']
emojis = emoji_pattern.findall(text)

print(len(emojis), 'chars found in post by', screen_name)
for emoji in emojis:
    print('emoji: ' + json.dumps(emoji))

2 chars found in post by fred
Character: "\ud83d\ude4c"
Character: "\ud83d\udca9"
```

(This assumes that only the characters in the range U+1F300 to U+1F64F count as real emoji. There are other characters that could arguably be classed as emoji, but that's another can of worms. Plus future Unicode versions may add more new characters.)

(Side-note: `\U` in `re` will not work for users of ‘narrow’ Python builds before Python 3.3.)

Comment: Great answer! For anyone else using tweepy for the same purpose, you can skip the json.loads command by using `dict_input = status._json`, where `status` is the item of the timeline fetched, as shown in the tweepy documentation [here](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html)